# I am getting this error [Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'classes LIKE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression

Tags: symfony

The following is a code where p.classes is foreign key. When the query will fire then its shows error like this :

> Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'classes LIKE': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

```
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM StudentBundle:Student  p WHERE p.classes  LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name','%'.$keyword.'%');
```

Kindly need solution on this.

Comment: Most probably you are trying to do a like search on a related field. If there is a relation between Student and Class, you will get this error.

Comment: yes there is realation between them. So how to overcome this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'Select p
     From StudentBundle:Student p
     Where p.classes c
     And c.name LIKE :name');

$query->setParameter('name','%'.$keyword.'%');
```

Wrote you the code, you need to give him an attribute of your class, not the class hitself.

Comment: @Poney I have added your code its showing [Syntax Error] line 0, col 54: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'c'. I think instead of "LIKE" we can use other one?

Comment: My code isnt complete, you have to change something, c.name, its c.something, something is the name of the attribute you want to compare with the keyword.
And I did a huge mistake.. :)
Its not Where but Join, and so its not And but Where.

Sorry for that huge error :p

Comment: Mark it as aswered :)